# F# events not working inside Async workflow

Tags: asynchronous, events, f#, agents, mailboxprocessor

I want to do a Post-Fire-Reply to an agent. Basically the agent triggers an event then replies to the caller. However I either keep getting a timeout error or the events do not fire correctly. I tried doing Post-Fire, that stopped the timeout errors but the events do not fire.

```
let evt = new Event<int>()
let stream = evt.Publish

type Agent<'T> = MailboxProcessor<'T>
type Fire = Fire of int

let agent = Agent.Start(fun inbox -> 
    let rec loop() = async {
        let! msg = inbox.Receive()
        let (Fire i) = msg
        evt.Trigger i }
    loop())

let on i fn = 
    stream 
    |> Observable.filter (fun x -> x = i) 
    |> Observable.filter (fun x -> x <> 1)
    |> Observable.subscribe (fun x -> fn x) 

let rec collatz n =
    printfn "%d" n
    on n (fun i -> 
        if (i % 2 = 0) then collatz (i/2)
        else collatz (3*n + 1)) |> ignore

    agent.Post (Fire n) // this does not work
    // evt.Trigger n // this does works


collatz 13
```

This is a simple experiment that repeatedly creates a function to find the next number in the Collatz series and then calls itself to return the value until it reaches 1.

What seems to happen is that the trigger only fires once. I tried experimenting with every combination of Async.RunSynchronously / Async.Start / StartChild / SynchronizationContext that I could think of but no progress. I found a [blog](http://tomasp.net/blog/agent-event-reporting.aspx/) similar to what I am doing but that didn't help me neither

**EDIT**
Thank you Fyodor Soikin for pointing out my oversight. The original problem still remains in that I wish to both fire events and reply with a result, but get a timeout.

```
let evt = new Event<int>()
let stream = evt.Publish

type Agent<'T> = MailboxProcessor<'T>
type Command = 
    | Fire of int
    | Get of int * AsyncReplyChannel<int>

let agent = Agent.Start(fun inbox -> 
    let rec loop() = async {
        let! msg = inbox.Receive()
        match msg with
        | Fire i -> evt.Trigger i 
        | Get (i,ch) -> 
            evt.Trigger i 
            ch.Reply(i)
        return! loop() }
    loop())

let on i fn = 
    stream 
    |> Observable.filter (fun x -> x = i) 
    |> Observable.filter (fun x -> x <> 1)
    |> Observable.subscribe (fun x -> fn x) 

let rec collatz n =
    printfn "%d" n
    on n (fun i -> 
        if (i % 2 = 0) then collatz (i/2)
        else collatz (3*n + 1)) |> ignore

    agent.PostAndReply (fun ch -> (Get (n, ch))) |> ignore // timeout
    agent.PostAndAsyncReply (fun ch -> (Get (n, ch))) |> Async.Ignore |> Async.Start // works but I need the result
    agent.PostAndAsyncReply (fun ch -> (Get (n, ch))) |> Async.RunSynchronously |> ignore // timeout

collatz 13
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `loop` function doesn't loop. It receives the first message, triggers the event, and then just... exits. Never attempts to receive a second message.

You need to make that function work continuously: process the first message, then go right back to receive the next one, then go receive the next one, and so on. Like this:

```
let agent = Agent.Start(fun inbox -> 
    let rec loop() = async {
        let! msg = inbox.Receive()
        let (Fire i) = msg
        evt.Trigger i
        return! loop() }
    loop())
```

---

### Edit

Since you've reached your limit on questions, I will answer your edit here.

The reason you're getting timeouts in your second snippet is that you have a deadlock in your code. Let's trace the execution to see that.

1. **THREAD 1**: The agent is started.
2. **THREAD 2**: The first `collatz` call.
3. **THREAD 2**: The first `collatz` call posts a message to the agent.
4. **THREAD 1**: The agent receives the message.
5. **THREAD 1**: The agent triggers the event.
6. **THREAD 1**: As a result of the event, the second `collatz` call happens.
7. **THREAD 1**: The second `collatz` call posts a message to the agent.
8. **THREAD 1**: The second `collatz` call starts waiting for the agent to respond.

And this is where the execution ends. The agent cannot respond at this point (in fact, it cannot even receive the next message!), because its instruction pointer is still inside `evt.Trigger`. The `evt.Trigger` call hasn't yet returned, so the `loop` function hasn't yet recursed, so the `inbox.Receive` function hasn't yet been called, so the second message is still waiting in the agent's queue.

So you get yourself a classic deadlock: `collatz` is waiting for the agent to receive its message, but the agent is waiting for `collatz` to finish handling the event.

The simplest, dumbest solution to this would be to just trigger the event asynchronously:

```
    async { evt.Trigger i } |> Async.Start
```

This will make sure that the event handler is executed not "right there", but asynchronously, possibly on a different thread. This will in turn allow the agent not to wait for the event to be processed before it can continue its own execution loop.

In general though, when dealing with multithreading and asynchrony, one should never call unknown code directly. The agent should never directly call `evt.Trigger`, or anything else that it doesn't control, because that code might be waiting on the agent itself (which is what happened in your case), thus introducing the deadlock.

Comment: Grr. I must have missed that when I copy/pasted while experimenting. I will try and see if that helps, but that originally was in my code.

Comment: You might have had the `loop()` there without the `do!`

Comment: do! should NOT be used for recursive calls, because it leaks memory. Use return! instead. http://fsharpnews.blogspot.fi/2010/10/memory-leaks-in-asynchronous-workflows.html

Comment: Thank you for the tip, that fixed that issue! I've been staring at this for too long. Unfortunately it didn't solve my original problem. See my edit for details.

Comment: If you have a completely different question from what you were originally asking, please make a separate post.

Comment: I don't think it's a different question personally. Besides I have reached my limit of asking 1 question for now

Comment: Ok, since you've reached your limit, I have answered the question here. In the future though, please do not create an iterating conversation out of your questions. This is against the purpose of SO, which is supposed to be a community-reusable Q&A site.